# How to create an Edit button for each row from a 2d array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 2d array in php that displays the table contents and I was able to create an edit icon for each row. However, I am having trouble retrieving the data from the selected row.

Here's how I populated my array:

```
<?php
//use query to retrieve columns
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);// contains the query that creates 2d

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) { //returns current row 1d 
  $fields[] = $record['0'];//takes first element from record called fields (table names)
}

//retrieve the table content since data table has rows and columns
//lets use 2d array
$data2dArr = array();

//retrieve all columns without listing them explicitly, for the sort
if ($dir == 0) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  $table_name ORDER BY $fields[$cn]";  //ascending
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  $table_name ORDER BY $fields[$cn] DESC"; //descending
}
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $i = 0;  // counter
  //each element in array line 
  foreach ($line as $col_value) {
    $data2dArr[$i][] = $col_value; // is stored in col value, dataarr used for display
    $i++;
  }
}

?>
```

First, I printed the values in my 2d array like this:

```
<?php
for ($j = 0; $j < count($data2dArr[0]); $j++) {
 ?>
    <tr>
        <?php
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($fields); $k++) {
        ?>
            <td><?php print $data2dArr[$k][$j]; print $j;? </td>

        <?php
        }
        //added the Edit button here
        ?>
         <th><input type="image" src="images/edit.png" onclick="openForm()"/</th>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
```

In my edit.php file, I have the same array above but inside the 2nd for loop, contains:

```
<td><input name="field<?php echo $k ?>" id="field<?php echo $k ?>" placeholder="<?php print $data2dArr[$k][$j] ?>" class="full-width" type="text"> </td
```

the purpose is print the selected row x that contains y columns but the solution above prints out all of the elements. I know that it's because all contents in my table are being put in my input<> for each iteration, what I cannot figure out is how to print just the fields of the column from selected row.

For example,
From the table called Student

```
student_number | name | class| major  |
22             | Rick |  3   | CS     | editButton 
32             | Ross |  5   | Math   | editButton
```

If I select the student number from the second row, I expect my input placeholder to have `|32|Ross|5|Math`

I would like to know how do I go about this? Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you convenient to show a sample of your array?

Comment: Ok, I added where the array is created

Answer (score 0):

You question is kinda long and confusing so I assume you have problem to print specific 
field in the array?

You can try:

```
foreach($data2dArr as $key => $value){
    print $data2dArr[$key]["student_number"]."|".$data2dArr[$key]["name"]."|".$data2dArr[$key]["class"]."|".$data2dArr[$key]["major"];
}
```

*It is better to show less of your code and explain briefly yet clearly what are you trying to achieve*

Comment: If I have an Edit button for each row, how do I retrieve the data from that row?

Comment: do you mean _how should you print the row with the edit button together_?

Comment: `print '<td><input name="field'.$value["student_number"].'" id="field'.$value["student_number"].'" placeholder=".$data2dArr[$key]["student_number"].'|'.$data2dArr[$key]["name"].'|'.$data2dArr[$key]["class"].'|'.$data2dArr[$key]["major"].'" class="full-width" type="text"> </td>'`